# Build alex auto sdk for Android failure

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Can't build alex auto sdk for android

```
./build.sh oe -t androidarm

./build.sh oe -t androidarm
```

> |
>   /home/rhuang/ba/alexa/aac-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-22/work/x86_64-linux/pseudo-native/1.8.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o):
>   In function `fts5Bm25Function': | (.text+0x2de74): undefined reference
>   to`log' | collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status | make: ***
>   [bin/pseudo] Error 1 | make:**  Waiting for unfinished jobs.... |
>   /home/rhuang/ba/alexa/aac-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-22/work/x86_64-linux/pseudo-native/1.8.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o):
>   In function `fts5Bm25Function': | (.text+0x2de74): undefined reference
>   to`log' | collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status | make: 
>   **[bin/pseudodb] Error 1 |
>   /home/rhuang/ba/alexa/aac-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-22/work/x86_64-linux/pseudo-native/1.8.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o):
>   In function `fts5Bm25Function': | (.text+0x2de74): undefined reference
>   to`log' | collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status | make: ***
>   [bin/pseudolog] Error 1 | ERROR: oe_runmake failed | WARNING: exit
>   code 1 from a shell command. | ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log
>   file is located at
>   /home/rhuang/ba/alexa/aac-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-22/work/x86_64-linux/pseudo-native/1.8.2-r0/temp/log.do_compile.8432) ERROR: Task
>   (virtual:native:/home/rhuang/bin/oe-core/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_1.8.2.bb:do_compile)
>   failed with exit code '1'

Comment: Hi robin, in order for us to help you with the problem you're having, you'll need to be clearer about what your problem is, and what you expect to happen. Check out the article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The better you explain your problem, the more likely it is that someone can help you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that "free text" has been enabled in SQLite3 and requires log support. Add the math-library (-lm) when linking the pseudo-native code.

In my example I am running API version 27 and Intel 64 bit and the change below works.

```
    $ vim alexa-auto-sdk/builder/build/tmp-android-<apiver>/work/<arch>/pseudo-native/1.8.2-r0/pseudo-1.8.2/Makefile.in 

    # needed for anything that links with pseduo_client.o, pretty much
    CLIENT_LDFLAGS=-ldl -lpthread  -lm
```